# Team Building Exercises to teach writing unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, legacy-code

I recently started working for a company with a very large legacy code base. Product is really good, and we have a large and happy customer base... but!

The codebase is a mess. It is a mix of Classic ASP and .NET. There are hardly any unit tests, and the code is less than testable. I can see that developers are losing confidence in the codebase, and it is acceptable to say "Well, with code this bad, why should I bother writing tests.", so people don't. Some have forgotten, and others have never started. The point is that even with easily testable bugs, tests are not written.

I am very close to convincing my boss to take a full week out of development, and dedicating this week to teaching and writing unit tests for the system. My plan is to start out with a half day of a lectures on unit testing, the second half I want to do some sort of team building exercise, that will teach people some basic testing skills. Then some days of pair programming unit tests for our system, and reviewing them in group discussions. With "teachers" to help out people with questions.

What I am looking for inspiration for is the team building exercise. I would like some "offline" exercise that I could do with them. We are about 40 people, so we can split up into groups.

The thing is that I can't find any such exercices anywhere. I don't know if people have done this before. One suggestion I had was to have people work on pseudo code, and then come up with testing strategies, but I think that is too "real". I would like it to bee a little more abstract, and not have people bring their hangups about programming, or fears of not performing.

Has anyone heard of anything like this, or does anyone have suggestions on what could work?

All input is greatly appreciated.

... oh and I get the impression that people would really appreciate something like this. So I do not anticipate a major push back when I announce this. Hopefully we can emerge out of this week with renewed confidence in our codebase!

Thanks JP

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best tool to get into uint testing is to play a group game of [FizzBuzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz).

You don't have to write any code to get the idea of what needs to be tested. To write the first few tests, you just start going through the first several numbers in the sequence and mentally decide what the output SHOULD be, and there's your test.

But when it's time to write the unit tests, the code that needs to be written is very non-threatening.

Comment: Most of these people know how to write a test, they just don't do it. So I was looking for an exercise to teach some of the more subtle points. Remove some of the blockers and fears. I think some of them are afraid of writing tests because they feel insecure or somehow inferior when it comes to testing. And I know they aren't. Does this make sense? I want to instill some testing confidence into my collegues :-)

Comment: I have tried looking for games you could play, but can't really find any out there. Maybe this isn't really an approach that people have taken.